# Categorize measures and dimensions according to Topic area

Tags: sql, ssas, olap-cube, ssas-2012

I have an SSAS cube which has Facts and Dimensions for two topics (Sales and Marketing). Each topic has its own facts and dimensions and there are some common dimensions too. Is there a way to categorize the Facts and Dimensions within the cube according to topic, in such a way that my Cube looks like this -

### Sales

Fact-1
Dimension-1

### Marketing

Fact-2
Dimension-2

### Common Dimensions

Dimension-3
Dimension-4

Answer (score 0):

If you have Enterprise edition you can create a Perspective for Sales and one for Marketing. Users will choose to connect to the appropriate perspective instead of the whole cube. Each perspective just shows a trimmed down field list.

Comment: I can create perspectives and then users can choose to connect to the appropriate perspective instead of the whole cube. But, is there any other way (apart from perspectives) to achieve this? Thanks !!

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Comment: @user3220846 One tip... In the Excel PivotTable field list there is a drop down of measure groups at the top. Choose one and it filters the field list to related dimensions. That may help.

Comment: @user3220846 what client tool do users use?

Comment: They use Excel PivotTable and I've already suggested using Perspectives and Measure groups drop down but I just wanted to check any other better method, if any. Thanks for your help !!!